# Div Appears on Hover

Tags: html, css, position

This is supposed to be a simple div-appear-on-hover situation, but the div with `#1949_neon` is just not showing up after I hover on `#1949_wrapper`.
I am very sure that the div is at the right place, because when I change the visibility to `block`, it's showing up at the right place.

```
<div id="1949_wrapper">
     <div class="year_line" style="top:170px;">1949</div>
     <div class="neon_light" id="1949_neon"></div>
</div>

.neon_light{
position:relative;  
top: 0px; 
width:250px; 
height:650px; 
background:#FFFF00;
z-index: 1;
}

#1949_neon {
display: none;
}

#1949_wrapper:hover #1949_neon {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with css. The issue here is your id's starting with a number. This works.

```
<div id="wrapper_1949">
     <div class="year_line" style="top:170px;">1949</div>
     <div class="neon_light" id="neon_1949"></div>
</div>

.neon_light{
    position:relative;  
    top: 0px; 
    width:250px; 
    height:650px; 
    background:#FFFF00;
    z-index: 1;
}

#neon_1949 {
    display: none;
}

#wrapper_1949:hover #neon_1949 {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just changed the name of the div and it works perfectly fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it just by css.

Change your HTML to

```
<div id="1949_wrapper" onmouseover="document.getElementById('1949_neon').style.display = 'block';">
    <div class="year_line" style="top:170px;">1949</div>
    <div class="neon_light" id="1949_neon"></div>
</div>
```

and your css to:

```
.neon_light {
    position:relative;
    top: 0px;
    width:250px;
    height:650px;
    background:#FFFF00;
    z-index: 1;
    display:none;
}
#1949_neon {
    display: none !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/XyXt8/)

Comment: Hi Amit, Thanks for your answer! Now the div appears, but it won't disappear after I move the mouse away. Is there any way you can help me fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Try this:http://jsfiddle.net/AmitJoki/XyXt8/1/, don't forget to mark my answer as answer and upvote it ;)

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thanks a lot! (I've picked this as the answer, but my level is too low to upvote anything yet...)

Comment: Glad to have helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS. What is going wrong with your CSS is you are having ID starting with a number which will not work. Here is the working CSS.

```
.neon_light{
position:relative;  
top: 0px; 
width:250px; 
height:650px; 
background:#FFFF00;
z-index: 1;
}

[id='1949_neon'] {
display: none;
}

[id='1949_wrapper']:hover [id='1949_neon'] {
  display: block;
}
```